# Replace new line character in freemarker

Tags: html, freemarker

Is there any way to replace the new line character on free marker? I am trying this:

```
<#assign str = str?replace("(\r\n)+", "</p><p>")>
```

which worked in Java, but not in freemarker. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. The replace function needs to know if the expresion is a regex, so I had to add 'r' as a [parameter](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_string_flags)

```
<#assign str = str?replace("(\r\n)+", "</p><p>",'r')>
```