# How to change java freemarker newline character from LF to CRLF?

Tags: java, freemarker

Is there a way to instruct freemarker to use(force) CrLf instead of the LF character?

Running on Windows 10, Using

- Java 1.8
- freemarker.jar version 2.3.20
- Jython 2.5.3 script to setup variables and execute the template engine

I tried injecting a newline with `${'\n'}` and `${'\r\n'}` as suggested by this [StackOverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108107/replace-new-line-character-in-freemarker) But it doesn't have any effect. The problem is that the JVM/freemarker runtime always prints LF, as if it replaces it itself.

But i need the \n to be as the platform, thus a CrLf since i'm on a Windows system. I assume there's some freemarker setting to force it, but i can't find it..

For the moment, i'm replacing the \n for \r\n in Jython when the freemarker-engine provides a chuck of output to the callback routine.

But that replacing negatively impacts other parts of software; 1) it results in all strings to be replaced which is resource intensive 2) some files come out differently than before which is not desired.

( i'm asking this again, because my previous post was marked duplicated with something which wasn't my problem. So i hope i stated my question more precisely this time. )